# how to get data from pivot table inside a many to one relation in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have 3 tables name like `"product"` , `"user"`, `"product_type"` so in my case *user and product_type having many to many relationship* and *user and product having one to many relationship* and *product and product_type having one to one relationship*.

I create one pivot table for user and product_type. inside that pivot table, I added one more column for description. so in product listing page I need to display description from that pivot table.

My code look like this:

```
Product::with('user)->with('product_type')->get();
```

Comment: Do you mean "user and product_type having many to many relationship" or do you mean you also have an `account_type` table?

Comment: sorry i mean product_type, actually  Product::with(['user'=>function($q){$q->with('product_type')}])->with('product_type')->get(); the above code is providing the pivot table data. But i need to filer using product_type_id.

Answer (score 1):

To get extra fields from pivot table you need to use withPivot in function of your model Like this:

```
public function product_type() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','product_type','product_id','user_id')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
    }
```

you may also refer laravel docs for it:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I already done everything also i'm getting the data using this query.
 actually Product::with(['user'=>function($q){$q->with('product_type')}])->with('product_type')->get(); the above code is providing the pivot table data. But i need to filer using product_type_id.

Currently i'm managing this things from frontend blade

Comment: First of all use this way to get the data  => Product::with('user.product_type')->get();   And Can you explain what exactly you want?

Comment: I'm getting all product types and related pivot data under the user. I need to get one product type related on that product table. NB:product and product_type having one to one relation, the product table having product_type_id